# How can I resolve background image URL inside sass file using webpack-4?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4, webpack-style-loader

this is my first time writing here so please bear that in mind. I'm first time using webpack in a project and I have a problem where I'm trying to set a background image using background url() function in my sass file, something like this:

```
.img-container {
  background: url('../../img/homepage-login-prog.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

My folder structure is:

```
- css
  | app.css
- dist (this folder is created after building for production)
- img
  | some-image.jpg
- js
  | app.js (entry point for webpack output, 
            this is where I import main.scss file)
- js-vendor
  | vendor.js (third-party libraries like bootstrap, jquery)
- sass  (this is where I keep all my sass files which get compiled using 
         webpack loaders)
  | components
    | greetings-section.scss
    | navbar.scss
  | main.scss
  | variables.scss
- template.html
- webpack.common.js
- webpack.dev.js
- webpack.prod.js
```

Because I have webpack configured both for development and production, I have separate files for both of them, where both extend on general (common) configuration file. That one looks like this:

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry:{
    main: "./js/app.js",
    vendor: "./js-vendor/vendor.js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: ["html-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(svg|png|jp(e*)g|gif)$/,
        use: [{
          loader: "file-loader",
          options: {
            name: "[name].[hash].[ext]",
            outputPath: "img",
          }
        }]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

My webpack dev configuration looks like this:

```
const common = require("./webpack.common");
const merge = require("webpack-merge");
const path = require("path");
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: "development",
  output: {
    filename: "[name].bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./template.html"
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "[name].[contentHash].min.css"
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            options: {
              publicPath: "../../"
            }
          },
          "css-loader",
          "sass-loader"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

So, after webpack-dev-server starts, it pops an error:

```
ERROR in ./sass/main.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./sass/main.scss)
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../img/homepage-login-prog.jpg' in 'C:\Users\...\...\...\sass'
```

As you can see I've tried setting a relative path using publicPath option in mini-css-extract-plugin, but it doesn't solve it for me.
I've also been reading that other people have similar problems, but none of their solutions worked for me, so what I'm trying to ask is, does anyone know how can i configure webpack to recognize the url of a image inside my sass files, and properly bind it?

Sorry for the long post, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

Ran into a similar problem and what worked for me was to move my main.scss file into my sass folder. Before, it was in the src folder. The main.scss file imports all my other .scss files. Inside my index.js, which is the entry point, I import the main.scss file.

My file structure however is different than yours.

[image: file structure]

I have a dist folder for the output, and the src folder for input.

index.js:

```
import "./sass/main.scss";
```

main.scss:

```
@import "./footer";
@import "./header";
@import "./home";
@import "./navigation";
@import "./reset";
@import "./typography";
@import "./variables";
```

_header.scss:

```
  #hero {
  background-image: url("../assets/heroImage.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

I have been getting the same exact error because of the background-image: url() problem in my scss code. This import structure solved it for me.

For my webpack, I have a very similar config split into 3, common, dev, and prod. The only plugin I added is 'resolve-url-loader' in webpack.dev. I've tried the publicpath in miniCssExtractPlugin to no avail.

My common is almost the exact same as yours except for the entrypoint. Mine is index.js in the src folder and not app.js.

webpack.dev.js

```
const path = require("path");
const common = require("./webpack.common");
const merge = require("webpack-merge");
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: "development",
  output: {
    filename: "[name].bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./src/template.html"
    })
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "style-loader"
          },
          {
            loader: "css-loader"
          },
          {
            loader: "resolve-url-loader"
          },
          {
            loader: "sass-loader"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

This solved it for me after countless hours. Let me know if you this helps in any way. Cheers.

Comment: this should work -
background-image: url("./assets/heroImage.jpg");

Answer (score 5):

Problem is not in the webpack. Your problem is in the background url path. As you have imported all css to a single main.scss you need to do the following in the backgroud url -

```
.img-container {
      background: url('./../img/homepage-login-prog.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
      background-size: cover;
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

## Best Solution

I also had this issue and the only solution I found is to use `~` to reference the very root directory and accessing public folder from there.

```
background-image: url("~/public/images/icon.png");
```

And this is working fine for me :)

**OR** And the other alternative would be to move images to the `src` directory, and this won't be a problem since webpack would pack them in a folder called `static/media` as static files

Answer (score 1):

You could also try out [resolve.modules](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvemodules) for both relative and absolute paths.
By adding to your config file:

```
module.exports = {
  ...,
  resolve: {
    modules: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, "img"),
      "node_modules"
    ],
  },
  ...
}
```

You could then access your image from your sass file with:

```
background-image: url("~homepage-login-prog.jpg");
```

Or with replace the tilde with the relative path.

Answer (score 0):

From: 
`background-image: url('../../image/section1image.jpg');`
To : 
`background-image: url('~../../image/section1image.jpg');`

Add ~ at the beginning of the url (this works for me). Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

This kind of image is a static resource for webpack. So you can use [`url-loader`](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/url-loader/) to load.

To install it:

```
npm install url-loader --save-dev
```

In your webpack config file use url-loader in loaders

```
{
  test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
  loader: 'url-loader'
}
```

Comment: It still doesn't work, I still get the same error :/ In case you missed it, i am using file-loader to resolve all types of images, but that only works if i already have an image with the src attribute in my html. I need a way to load urls of a background images from sass :/ Still thank you for quick response, hopefully someone else will come up with solution.

Answer (score -1):

```
npm install url-loader --save-dev
```

and

```
{
  test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
  loader: 'url-loader'
}
```

This is solution for me, thx!

Answer (score -1):

Try giving height and width

```
.img-container {
     background: url('../../img/homepage-login-prog.jpg');
     background-size: cover;
     width: 100px;
     height: 100px;
}
```

or giving some padding

```
.img-container {
    background: url('../../img/homepage-login-prog.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    padding: 100px;
}
```

or add some content in the HTML tag having `.img-container` class.